# Can we have JSON object as input parameter to http get for RESTful web services?

Tags: json

I am new to RESTful web services. Can i have a method like below which accepts JSON as object ?

```
@GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Consumes("application/json")
   @Path("/test")
   public Response modifyJson(JSONObject input);
```

Comment: please put three spaces in front of your first `@POST`, then everything will be fine with code highlighting. (you need in each line 4, you have only 1 in first line of code)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that by default it is not possible to send Json as input to a GET, only other verbs (POST, PUT...)

Having said that, technically it depends of the service to allow you or not to send input on GET. The usual is to send query string parameters with GET.

Hope it helps

Ademar

Comment: Thank you for the info. So i hope technically it is possible.

Comment: But if it does not, couldnt you send query string instead? I'd think once you have the info you want to send and the url, the change would not be that big. I am obviously guessing here....